# linux pipe with egrep not working as expected

Tags: regex, linux, bash, pipe, sh

I have this small piece of code

```
 egrep -oh '([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)' -R /path | uniq | sort
```

I use this script to dig for environment variables inside files stored in a common directory when I don't want to display any duplicate, but I just want the the name of any variable if any are being used.

needless to say that the regex works, the matched words are the ones that are composed of 3 subsets of letters in uppercase `*_*_*`, the problem is that `uniq` doesn't look like it's work and doing anything, the variables are just printed out as `egrep` finds them.

Not even `uniq -u` does the trick.

Is the pipe itself the problem ?

Comment: You have the order of `sort` and `uniq` reversed.

Comment: The order is inverted. `... | sort | uniq`

Comment: sort should go first, and then uniq

Comment: @BroSlow why ? `uniq` doesn't cache the results ?

Comment: @user2485710 It's not about caching the results, `uniq` checks adjacent values against each other, so you need to sort first.

Comment: @user2485710 No, `uniq` would remove consecutive duplicates.

Comment: @BroSlow oh snap ... thanks, now it works as expected, I don't know how I missed that .

Comment: `uniq` is entirely superfluous if you use `sort -u` instead

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I know that, somehow I was focused on how to get a pipe work with `uniq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uniq requires its input to be sorted if you want it to work in this manner.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq): *(emphasis mine)*

> DESCRIPTION: Filter **adjacent** matching lines

So you could put a `sort` before the `uniq` in the pipeline, but that is not necessary, you can simply use the `-u` flag to `sort` to only output unique lines from the sorted output:

```
egrep -oh '([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)' -R /path | sort -u
```